# Chart.js creating a line graph using dates

Tags: javascript, date, chart.js, ejs

I can't seem to get Chart.js to work with dates. I have tried quite a few different methods:

```
let examChart = document.getElementById("examChart").getContext("2d");
let examLineChart = new Chart(examChart, {
    type: "line",
    data: [
            { t: new Date("2015-3-15 13:3"), y: 12 },
            { t: new Date("2015-3-25 13:2"), y: 21 },
            { t: new Date("2015-4-25 14:12"), y: 32 }
    ],
    options: {
        label: "placeholder"
    }
});
```

And:

```
let examChart = document.getElementById("examChart").getContext("2d");
let examLineChart = new Chart(examChart, {
    type: "line",
    data: [
            { t: "2015-3-15 13:3", y: 12 },
            { t: "2015-3-25 13:2", y: 21 },
            { t: "2015-4-25 14:12", y: 32 }
    ],
    options: {
        label: "placeholder"    
    }
});
```

And:

```
let examChart = document.getElementById("examChart").getContext("2d");
let examLineChart = new Chart(examChart, {
    type: "line",
    data: [
            { t: "Sun Mar 15 2015 12:03:45 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)", y: 12 },
            { t: "Wed Mar 25 2015 12:02:15 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)", y: 21 },
            { t: "Sat Apr 25 2015 13:12:30 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)", y: 32 }
    ],
    options: {
        label: "placeholder"    
    }
});
```

To cover just a few of my attempts, I just can't seem to get how to set dates properly even after reading the documentation (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) (they don't actually give an example)

The HTML being used:

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="examChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

I just have no idea, although I imagine this is a rather simple problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to move your data within a `dataset`. If you take a look at the [usage manual](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html), a `datasets` array is used. The *"hint"* for datasets within the docs for [time](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#data-sets) is also not that obvious (See headline).

**See the snippet below:**

I just copied the basic usage example and inserted the data from your first attempt (+ added few labels)

**UPDATE 18.03.2020**

I've updated the snippet to use Chart.js `2.8.0` and added following code, as suggested in the comment by [@Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2543816/erik)

```
options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time'
      }]
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE 16.02.2021**

As pointed out by [@habib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10029265/habib), the 2.9.4 version was throwing couple of errors. I guess that those were caused by missing dependency (moment.js). See:

> Note: starting v2.8, Moment.js is an optional dependency for Chart.js and Chart.min.js. In order to use the time scale with Moment.js, you need to make sure Moment.js is fully loaded before requiring Chart.js. You can either use a shim

[Source](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#require-js)

Therefore, I changed following things:

- Updated Chart.js to 2.9.4
- Added moment.js (2.29.1) as dependency
- Adjusted the time format to be ISO8601 compliant (As suggested by [soiboi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11444719/soiboi))

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("examChart").getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
      }]
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels: ["2015-03-15T13:03:00Z", "2015-03-25T13:02:00Z", "2015-04-25T14:12:00Z"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Demo',
      data: [{
          t: '2015-03-15T13:03:00Z',
          y: 12
        },
        {
          t: '2015-03-25T13:02:00Z',
          y: 21
        },
        {
          t: '2015-04-25T14:12:00Z',
          y: 32
        }
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="examChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This example displays the data points as evenly spread across the x axis, this shouldn't be. The x axis should be a scale and the points should be positioned along this scale, the gaps in between points should be different.

Comment: Although not quite the solution I wanted, this is a solution and certainly helpful, thank you.

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light Did you figure out a way to do what you're saying?

Comment: @claudekennilol I did not figure out how to do it. Even today I wonder why such a feature is not standard.

Comment: add the following to get it to space out - options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time'
                    }]
                }
            }

Comment: this solution is giving an error on Chart.js/2.9.4
Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined

Comment: @habib Thanks for the hint, I updated the example and added a short summary of the changes.

Answer (score 10):

Building on what @RamizWachtler has answered, you can add to the options section of the chart to scale the times out properly. I'll note that this doesn't seem to work with Charts.js 2.3. Added a working snippet that uses the latest Charts.js version as of April 2019.

Additionally I've changed the time formatting to be ISO8601 compliant.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                distribution: 'linear'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Source - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("examChart").getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["2015-03-15T13:03:00Z", "2015-03-25T13:02:00Z", "2015-04-25T14:12:00Z"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Demo',
      data: [{
          t: "2015-03-15T13:03:00Z",
          y: 12
        },
        {
          t: "2015-03-25T13:02:00Z",
          y: 21
        },
        {
          t: "2015-04-25T14:12:00Z",
          y: 32
        }
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        distribution: 'linear'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0-rc.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="examChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply time on y-axis ?

Comment: To get this to work on more recent versions of chartjs you need to include momentjs file.

Answer (score 1):

when using time, you have to use UTC time, as your local time is added(australia +10 hours / 36000 secs) so every country has a different time zone.
the key is to use moment.utc in any conversion of time
0 seconds = moment.utc('1970-01-01 00:00:00')

use `moment.utc('1970-01-01').add(3600, 'seconds')`to add a value and then 
from y-axis values or tool tip items, you have to reference

```
callback: value => {
    date = moment.utc(value);
    if(date.diff(moment.utc('1970-01-01 23:59:59'), 'minutes') === 0) 
    {
        return null;
    };
    date.format('HH:mm:ss');
}

label: (item, data) => data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].label +" "+ 
moment.utc(data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].data[item.index]).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

https://lopeys.com/ironman/IMAUS_Charts_StackedTimes.htm

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library to your project and format your dates using moment. Also I'm not sure about using the "t" and "y" here. I'd add the time as labels and matched that with the x data:

```
var data = {
  labels: [moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"), moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"), moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")],
  datasets: [
    {
        data: [12,21,32],
    }
  ]
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
data:data,
});
```

There is a fiddle example [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/supertopoz/jzns3nky/)

Comment: This example displays the data points as evenly spread across the x axis, this shouldn't be. The x axis should be a scale and the points should be positioned along this scale, the gaps in between points should be different.