# Chart.js major ticks are not showing while using ticks.source: "labels" on type: "timeseries"

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to show major ticks on the x-axis while using the type: "timeseries" option, but they are not showing.

My x-axis options:

```
xAxis: {
          bounds: "ticks",
          grid: {
            display: false,
          },
          type: "time",
          time: {
            unit: "hour",
            stepSize: 3,
            displayFormats: {
              day: "d. MMM",
              hour: "HH:mm",
            },
            tooltipFormat: "EEEE, MMM dd, HH:mm:ss",
          },
          adapters: {
            date: {
              locale: pl,
            },
          },
          ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: 7.1,
            // source: "labels",
            maxRotation: 0,
            major: {
              enabled: true,
            }
          },
        }
```

Without ticks.source: "labels" major ticks are showed.
How could I make it work with the source: "labels" option

Comment: If possible share part of JSON data, it will helpful for creating the same scenario from my end and test accordingly and from the graph which library you are using

Comment: You should share your code like this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68048609/line-graph-with-linear-timescale-in-chart-js